# Firebase realtime database authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to make use of Firebase realtime database. I have created the data structure I want. You have members, rooms and the relation between them. Everyone in a room can "talk" to each other.

The json data structure:

```
{
  members : {
    "223dfa323" : {
      name : "Test member",
      os : "IOS",
      date_registered : "2017-02-02",
      enabled : true

    },
    "ddfa33434" : {
      name : "Test member 2",
      os : "Android",
      date_registered : "2017-02-03",
      enabled : true
    },
    "3434" : {
      name : "Test member 3",
      os : "Android",
      date_registered : "2017-02-03",
      enabled : true
    }

  },

  rooms : {
    "1234" : {
      name : "Room 1",
      date_created : "2017-02-02",
      enabled : true

    },
    "2312" : {
      name : "Room 2",
      date_registered : "2017-02-03",
      enabled : true
    }
  },

  roommembers : {
    "1234" : {
      members : {
        "223dfa323" : true,
        "ddfa33434" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But how can I prevent that others can access that data? How can I give members access to the own data? Member 3434 has no access to room 1234 for example, because it is not linked to it.

The other devices can access that data.

How can I do this in Firebase?

Comment: you can add the permited rooms in the user data.

Comment: You can secure access to the data with Firebase Database's server-side security rules. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) contains some great examples, as do [previous questions on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-security). I recommend starting there and reporting back (with your security rules) if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use firebase's [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/). In your case these could be:

```
"rules": {
    "rooms": {
        "$roomID": {
            ".read": .read": "root.child('roommembers/'+$roomID+'/members/'+auth.uid).exists()"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But what can I read then? Because I need to read all devices in that room if "my" device is in there.

Comment: I've edited my answer because I made a mistake. These rules allow any authenticated user to read any room's data (`name`, `date_created`, ..) only if their id is in `roommember/roomID/members` for the choosen room. I suggest you to take a look at the links Frank provided you in his comment